# Realizar una acción en php y luego ejecutar otra

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo un duda y no se como hacer, les explico tengo una tabla llamada post donde guardo mis post asta ahí todo bien, lo quiero hacer es que cuando yo presione **enviar datos** espere un rato para insertar y luego que me salga un modal diciendo si quiero ver mi **publicación** o **realizar otra**.

Si funciona pero el detalle esta que cuando precio **enviar** me carga el **modal** pero no me **guarda los datos**, como puedo hacer ya que le modal, lo llamo con javascript.

lo quiero hacer es que cuando presiono enviar espere un rato y luego me cargue el modal con el id correspondiente para ver la publicación y que el script se ejecuta al mismo tiempo.

```
    <?php //phpinfo(); 
#if (isset($_GET['enviar'])) {

if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    $titulo = trim($_POST['titulo']);
    $descripcion = trim($_POST['descripcion']);

    $queryinsert = "INSERT INTO tb_post(p_titulo,p_descripcion)VALUES('$titulo','$descripcion') ";

    $resultado =  mysqli_query($mysqli, $queryinsert);

    $ultimoid = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);

    echo $ultimoid;

    var_dump($resultado);
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($_POST);
}
if ($resultado === true) {


    $query_last = "SELECT
                     MAX(id_post) AS idPost
                     FROM
                     tb_post post";
    $rs = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query_last);
    //$array = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
        //$array[] = $row;
        $idPost = $row['idPost'];
        echo '<pre>';
        echo $idPost;
    }
}

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#enviar').on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#mymodal').modal('show');
        });
    });
</script>

  <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="titulo">
    <input type="text" name="descripcion">
    <input type="submit" value="enviar" name="enviar" id="enviar">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que lo que tienes es un problema de secuencialización en tu algoritmo.

Segun te entiendo lo que quieres es hacer el siguiente flujo:

```
Enviar->savePost->sendResponse(ID)->catchResponse(ID)->showModal(Post)
```

Para ello lo que se me ocurre es que lo hagas con Ajax, vas a tener que separar tu archivo en controlador y vista donde en el controlador vas a tener que poner todas las funciones (Crear y ver) y desde el Ajax vas a mandar la informacion para crear por metodo post y vas a tener que dar un response con un  `Return $insertedID;` de ahi vas a cachar desde Ajax ese ID y vas a enviarlo mediante otro Ajax a un controlador que te va a regresar un JSON con la informacion y ese Json es el que vas a tener que interpretar en tu modal.

Puedes ver un ejemplo del uso de Ajax para enviar informacion [Aqui](https://www.tothenew.com/blog/jquery-send-json-object-with-an-ajax-request/)

Ahora esa es la manera "correcta" de hacerlo, ya que basicamente estarias consumiendo y creando una API Rest sin embargo si lo que quieres es nada mas hacer que PHP espere puedes hacerlo con `sleep(timeInSeconds);` puedes ver un ejemplo de ello [aqui](https://www.jose-aguilar.com/blog/efecto-cargando-con-jquery-ajax/)